# How to save complete pdf document with plots and results with mathematica?

Tags: pdf, plot, wolfram-mathematica, document

I need to:

Analyse Data > Get plots and numerical results > Repeat for different sets of data > Make a document

The problem is that I need to create a pdf document for dozens of sets of data... Exporting and copying to a document separately those many graphs and numerical results is a really repetitive process and I'm trying to do that a bit faster, is there a way to do that?

The ideal would be to create a pdf document with: "plot and results + plot and results + plot and results + ..."

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Using Wolfram Mathematica for Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate this in the notebook you want to export as pdf:

```
Export["~/Desktop/nb.pdf", SelectedNotebook[]]
```

Comment: That's it! but I only want to export part of the notebook (I don't want to show the code), how can I do that?

Comment: I think you can close the cells, either manually or programmatically